# Calculator Test, implementing functions

Tags: c#

I'm solving this challenge, which is being created in the console application called "Calculator", and it wants me to create 4 methods which will relate to a calculator.

Methods to implement:
Add
Subtract
Multiply
Divide

Each method will accept two int numbers and they will return a value back.

But in a different console application called "Calculator tests", these methods will be called upon and values will be added. I have to run tests and if they are successful then the challenge is completed.

Check out the code below for the "Calculator tests".

I did mess around with the code so I did make some obvious mistakes, however, this has got me scratching my head.

I implemented the functions and added the two int numbers as the challenge commanded.

Originally I had some more cord, however, they were wrong and it didn't work for the challenge.

Code for Calculator:

```
using System;
namespace code_challenge.Challenges
{
    public class Calculator
    {
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Implement the add function below here
            public void Add(int num1, int num2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
            }

            // Implement the subtract function below here
            public void Subtract(int num1, int num2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
            }


            // Implement the multiply function below here
            public void Multiply(int num1, int num2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
            }

            // Implement the divide function below here
            public void Divide(int num1, int num2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
            }

        }
```

Code for CalculatorTests:

```
namespace code_challenge.Tests
{
    [TestFixture()]
    public class CalculatorTests
    {
        readonly Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

        [Test()]
        public void TestAddition()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(4, calculator.Add(2, 2));
        }

        [Test()]
        public void TestSubtraction()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(2, calculator.Subtract(4, 2));
        }

        [Test()]
        public void TestMultiplication()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(6, calculator.Multiply(2, 3));
        }

        [Test()]
        public void TestDivision()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(2, calculator.Divide(6, 3));
        }

    }
```

Expected result: Pass two int numbers in and have the Calculator Test function calculate with its default numbers.

Actual results: "The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item", "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point and the " 'Calculator' does not contain a definition for Add/Subtract/Multiply/Divide and no accessible extension method 'Add/Subtract/Multiply/Divide' accepting a first argument of type 'Calculator' could be found.

Comment: Why do you define the methods in `main`? You are supposed to define a `Calculator` class and define the methods there

Comment: A quote from your post: _Each method will accept two int numbers and they will return a value back_ According to the code you posted, all methods in class `Calculator` return `void`. Shouldn't they return `int` ?

Comment: Does your code even compile?

Comment: It does now, someone explained to me what I was doing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your Calculator's methods inside Main method as local functions. Public access modifier is not valid for local functions. That's why you are getting first error. That also seems to be the reason why your tests don't "see" the methods you are going to test (they are inside Main and are not visible).

I'm not able to tell you why your program doesn't have a suitable Main method as I don't see the rest of your code.

Actually, if your task is to write a class and unit tests for it, you could create a class library project inside which you write your Calculator class and a unit tests project where you create your unit tests. You don't have to create console application for that (unless you want to have other ways to interact with your Calculator, like using the Console).

Comment: Ucabov, Thanks for the info and to the rest of everyone else. This is part of a challenge that I got from a job. I only know the basics of C# and haven't even used it in months. I think I have a gist of what I need to do.